# How to call post service with parameters swift 3.0 Alamofire 4.0?

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire

I have parameters in

```
var Param : [String:String] = [:]
```

I am using

```
Alamofire.upload(
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
```

but in response it says `invalid service`
is their in parameter encoding it goes wrong ?

Comment: Can you send more details for your code?

Comment: You need to encode your parameter using URLEncoding(destination: .queryString)

Comment: Alamofire.upload(
            multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
         
                for (key, value) in Param {
                    multipartFormData.append(((value).data(using: .utf8))!, withName: key)
                }

Comment: It says me "invalid service" but same service in objective c working success

Comment: Share more code. Also check your URL. If there is special characters in it, then encoding required for that too.

Comment: Alamofire.upload(
            multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
         
                for (key, value) in Param {
                    multipartFormData.append(((value).data(using: .utf8))!, withName: key)
                }

Comment: @Dharini you want to upload image?

Comment: @Dharini If you find my answer help full the please upvote so other can also find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

multipartFormData is used to upload images on server. So if you want to upload image data then try to use below code.

```
let payload: [String: AnyObject] = [
"key1": "val1" as AnyObject,
"key2": true as AnyObject,
"key3" : [1,2,3,4] as AnyObject
]

let requestString = "http://www.url.com/api/action"

Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
    multipartFormData.append(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.photoImageView.image!, 0.5)!, withName: "photo_path", fileName: "swift_file.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
    for (key, value) in payload {
        multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
    }
    }, to: requestString, method: .post , headers:nil, encodingCompletion: { (result) in
    switch result {
    case .success(let upload, _, _):

        upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
            print(progress.fractionCompleted * 100)
        })

        upload.responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) in
        })
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)

    }
})
```

If you want to call the post request then try to use below code:

```
 let urlString = "https://httpbin.org/get"

Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: ["foo": "bar"],encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON {  
response in
  switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    print(response)

                    break
                case .failure(let error):

                    print(error)
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For swift 3, use the following code. It works very well in all my projects..

```
//Parameters

let paramDic : NSMutableDictionary = [
            "key1" : "value1",
            "key2" : "value2",
        ]

let urlString = "www.mywebsite.net/api/"
let url : URL = URL.init(string: urlString)!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)

//Setting HTTP method GET/POST/PUT
request.httpMethod = "POST"

//Setting header

request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

//Setting parameters

request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: paramDic!, options: [])



if paramDic != nil {
            request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: paramDic!, options: [])
        }

alamoFireManager!.request(request as URLRequestConvertible).responseJSON {
            response in
            switch response.result {
            case .failure(let error):
                print("\(urlString) failure response -> \n NSHTTPURLResponse ->\(response.response) \n \(error)")
            case .success :
                print("\(urlString) success response -> \n NSHTTPURLResponse ->\(response.response) \n Data -> \(response.result.value as? NSDictionary)")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The first Answer is for simple post API. If you want to post Multipart data then use the following Method..

```
 /**
     Call this to create a request with any HTTP method

     - parameter httpMethodType: HTTP method type post,get etc
     - parameter headers:        HTTP header key-value pair (no need to Content-Type,Accept)
     - parameter serviceName:    name of service which need to call
     - parameter paramDic:       parameters in key-value pair
     - parameter files:          array of NSData objects for file content
     - parameter success:        success callback handler
     - parameter failure:        failure callback handler
     */
    func uploadFileRequestWithParameters(_ paramDic : NSMutableDictionary?, files: NSMutableArray?, headers : NSMutableDictionary?, serviceName : NSString, success: @escaping (( _ response : HTTPURLResponse?, _ data : NSDictionary?) -> Void), failure: @escaping ((_ error : Error? ) -> Void)) {

        let urlString = BASE_URL + (serviceName as String)
        let url : URL = URL.init(string: urlString)!
        var headerDic = [String : String]()
        headerDic["Content-Type"] = "multipart/form-data"

        if headers != nil {
            let allHeaders : NSArray = headers!.allKeys as NSArray
            for key in allHeaders {
                headerDic[(key as? String)!] = (headers!.object(forKey: key)! as? String)
            }
        }
        print("Full HTTP URL -> \(urlString)")
        print("HTTP Request Method -> POST")
        print("Full HTTP Headers -> \(headerDic)")
        print("Full HTTP Parameters -> \(paramDic)")
        print("Files Array -> \(files)")

        // Begin upload

        alamoFireManager?.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in

            // import image to request
            for (file)  in files! {
                var mimeTypeStr = ""
                let fileDic : NSDictionary = file as! NSDictionary
                if (fileDic.object(forKey: "fileType") as? String == "image" ) {
                    mimeTypeStr = "image/png";
                }
                else if (fileDic.object(forKey: "fileType") as? String == "video" ) {
                    mimeTypeStr = "video/mp4";
                }
                else if (fileDic.object(forKey: "fileType") as? String == "gif" ) {
                    mimeTypeStr = "image/gif";
                }
                multipartFormData.append(fileDic.object(forKey: "fileData") as! Data, withName: fileDic.object(forKey: "fileKey") as! String, fileName: fileDic.object(forKey: "fileName") as! String, mimeType: mimeTypeStr)
            }

            // import parameters
            for (key, value) in paramDic! {
                multipartFormData.append((value as! String).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key as! String)
            }
        },
        usingThreshold: SessionManager.multipartFormDataEncodingMemoryThreshold, to: url, method: .post, headers: headerDic as [String : String], encodingCompletion: {
                    encodingResult in

            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in
                    debugPrint(response)
                    print(response.result.value as? NSDictionary)
                })

            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        })
    }
```

Call above method from your class like this.

```
 let image : UIImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "splash")
        let imgData : Data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!
        // let fileArray : NSArray = NSArray.init(objects: imgData)

        let parameters : NSMutableDictionary = [
            "name" : "Krishna",
        ]
        //Array to store file data
        let filesArray : NSMutableArray = []
        //fileType = image/video/gif
        //fileKey = api parameter key to receive file
        //Dictionary to hold the individual file data
        let file1 : NSMutableDictionary = [
            "fileData" : imgData,
            "fileName" : "profileImage.png",
            "fileType" : "image",
            "fileKey" : "userProfileImg"
        ]
        let file2 : NSMutableDictionary = [
            "fileData" : imgData,
            "fileName" : "video.mp4",
            "fileType" : "video",
            "fileKey" : "myVideoKey"
        ]
        let file3 : NSMutableDictionary = [
            "fileData" : imgData,
            "fileName" : "image.gif",
            "fileType" : "gif",
            "fileKey" : "myGIFKey"
        ]
        //Adding all file data dictionaries to array
        filesArray.add(file1)
        filesArray.add(file2)
        filesArray.add(file3)

        let header : NSMutableDictionary  = [
        "version": "1.0",
        "os": "iOS",
        "token" : HEADER_TOKEN
    ]

       uploadFileRequestWithParameters(paraDic, files: files , headers: header, serviceName: UPDATE_PROFILE_API as NSString, success: { (response, data) in
         } , failure: { (error) in

    })
```