# Alamofire - Ambiguous reference to member 'upload(_:to:method:headers:)'

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire, xcode8

```
 Alamofire.upload(media_data, to: WATSONCLOUD.API, method: .post, headers: header).responseJSON{
    (response) in switch response.result{
       case .Success(let JSON):
          print("Success with JSON: \(JSON)")
          callback(success: JSON as? NSDictionary, error: nil)

       case .Failure(let error):
          callback(success: nil, error: error)
          print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> Ambiguous reference to member 'upload(_:to:method:headers:)'

and I've no idea how to solve this tried different stuff but no success.

Comment: Don't use offensive language here. You can just ask him politely. Remember one thing, you need help...not we. Otherwise someone will flag this comment.

Comment: @Varun, did you try uploading using MultiPart in upload method ?

Comment: you can mark it as duplicate when it's actually a duplicate but without reading it properly marking it as duplicate is not fine, if you can answer if not let others do it @Poles

Comment: no @KrishnaDattShukla will try it since i'm pretty new to development and iOS can you provide me a example

Comment: Are you sure `WATSONCLOUD.API` is a string and hearder is a `[String : String]` dictionary? I think you have type mismatch in the arguments. I am pretty much sure because this function is working fine for me.

Comment: Okay @VarunKumar, I am adding Answer. please check it out..

Check this answer given by me on another question..

http://stackoverflow.com/a/40907477/5172413

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try below Method

```
    Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: ["foo": "bar"],encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON {  
response in
  switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    print(response)

                    break
                case .failure(let error):

                    print(error)
                }
}
```