# Swift 3 upload image to PHP-Server

Tags: php, swift, image, upload

I am trying to upload a simple image from iOS Photo Library or Camera
to my server using PHP 5.4
Moving the uploaded file fail, assuming $_FILES contains no data

```
func uploadImage() {
    let image = self.imageView.image!
    //let image = UIImage.init(named: "myImage")

    let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)!

    print(imgData)

    let parameters = ["name": "Frank Bergmann"]

    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "userfile",fileName: "file.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
        for (key, value) in parameters {
            multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
        }
    },
                     to:"https://myserver.de/apple_imageupload.php")
    { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):

            upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
            })

            upload.responseJSON { response in
                print(response.result.value!)  
            }

        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)  
        }
    }
}
```

SWIFT 3 with Alamofire

PHP-Code on server

```
<?php
//$files = print_r($_FILES, 1);
//echo json_encode($files);

$uploaddir = "../bookcase/";

$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    $data=Array("Reply"=>"Image $file saved at server (bookcase)");
} else {
    $data=Array("Reply"=>"Image not saved - Name:".$_FILES['userfile']['name']);
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Output in xcode

```
Select Button pressed
Upload Button pressed
208743 bytes
{"Reply":"Image not saved - Name:"}
```

Assuming $_FILES is not present after upload - can help me anyone

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload image to server - Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41032678/upload-image-to-server-swift-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the "1" in your declare for imgData to 0.1

```
let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.1)!
```

That changes the quality of the image uploaded. Where 1 being the highest quality and 0 being the lowest (most compressed). I had the same issue when I used "1" but worked for me when I set to a lower quality. The image quality was noticeably bad for me so this solution may work for you too. You can also try another quality/compression amount, such as 0.2 or 0.5 or higher. That may also work for you, you just have to test it.

I speculate the reason for this is that the image was too big (when not compressed) for the server to handle it.

Comment: Thanks :) I will try, maybe it will working then. Meanwhile I solved it with a webview and php upload.